# non hardening thread compound

Tags: tools

I have a situation where I need something on a bolt threads to hold it in place but need to adjust this bold occasionally, something to just hold it firm. the bolt is a bolt adjuster and and is never tight. (some kind of firm gooey stuff)
 I have seen it but cant remember what it is called.

Comment: have a look at Loctite products : they do everything from a simple gentle thread lock to stuff where the bolt will break first....

Comment: use two nuts and torque them against each other.

Comment: If you want non-locking, are you thinking of plumbers putty? Otherwise threadlocker is the way to go, they have various strengths.

Comment: Could you replace it with a [mechanically locking bolt](http://nylok.com/products/nylok-torq-strip)?

Answer (score 1):

I'd recommend Loctite Blue 242 - Comes loose with hand tools, but won't shake loose. Don't use Loctite Red; that needs 500degrees heat, plus tools, to come loose.

From their website; "Loctite® Threadlocker Blue 242 is particularly suited for applications on less active substrates such as stainless steel and plated surfaces, where disassembly is required for servicing."

For added confusion; Loctite Blue comes in a Red package, as does Loctite Red. Make sure you read the label! :)

Comment: Yea, the color confusion is one of the dumbest things I've ever seen in a product...  For a time they were both in the [opposite colored tubes](https://i.redd.it/kz48lso3wmsy.jpg)...